# HuggingFace text summarization input data format issue

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, summarization

I’m trying to fine-tune a model to perform text summarization. I’m using `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained()`, so the following applies to several models (e.g. T5, ProphetNet, BART).

I’ve created a class called `CustomDataset`, which is a subclass of `torch.utils.Dataset`. That class contains one field: `samples` - a list of dictionaries that have `encodings` and `labels` keys. Each of the values in each of those dictionaries is a `torch.Tensor`. Here’s what an entry in `samples` looks like:

`{'encoding': tensor([[21603, 10, 188, 563, 1]]), 'label': tensor([[ 1919, 22003, 22, 7, 1]])}`

Here’s how I’m attempting to fine-tune the model using Trainer:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

training_args = TrainingArguments("test_trainer")
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=data,
)
trainer.train()
```

The error I’m getting gets thrown on line 63 in `transformers\data\data_collator.py`. Here’s that line of code:

`label = first["label"].item() if isinstance(first["label"], torch.Tensor) else first["label"]`

Here’s the error message:
`ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars`

I understand why the error message specifically is being thrown - the `first["label"]` tensor isn’t a one-element tensor, and hence `item()` can’t be called on it. That’s not why I’m asking this question, though.

I’m assuming that I’m not passing the data correctly, but it seems to me that `Trainer` should take care of `input_ids` and `decoder_input_ids` on its own. I’ve tried to set those manually (passing the `encodings` as `input_ids` and the `labels` as `decoder_input_ids`) and the model can successfully perform inference, but I haven’t managed to fine-tune it. Where am I making a mistake and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the name `label_ids` instead of `label` fixes the specific problem. `label` should be used if the label is either an `int`, a `float` or a one-element `torch.Tensor`. For tensors with multiple elements, use `label_ids`. See `data_collator.py`, lines 62-71 for details:

```
if "label" in first and first["label"] is not None:
    label = first["label"].item() if isinstance(first["label"], torch.Tensor) else first["label"]
    dtype = torch.long if isinstance(label, int) else torch.float
    batch["labels"] = torch.tensor([f["label"] for f in features], dtype=dtype)
elif "label_ids" in first and first["label_ids"] is not None:
    if isinstance(first["label_ids"], torch.Tensor):
        batch["labels"] = torch.stack([f["label_ids"] for f in features])
    else:
        dtype = torch.long if type(first["label_ids"][0]) is int else torch.float
        batch["labels"] = torch.tensor([f["label_ids"] for f in features], dtype=dtype)
```

Also, the name `input_ids` should be used instead of `encoding`. Otherwise, an `unknown kwarg` error gets thrown.

Comment: I'm also facing an issue with input data, please visit the question on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75399318/runtimeerror-could-not-infer-dtype-of-dict

after changing the labels to label_ids. I'm getting an error
```
KeyError: 0
```